# Access Kinect SDKs Facetracking data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kinect

I would like to access the FTResult from Kinect SDKs facetracking feature in JavaScript.

Kinect SDK 1.8 includes a "Web application" feature and corresponding sample file that shows access to skeleton data and real-time stream but lacks support for facetracking data (AFAIK).

What would be the easiest way to make these data available in JavaScript?
I can't think of a better way than creating another WebSocket server and send the data in parallel, however it would be great if the existing WebSocket present in "KinectWebserver.cs" could be utilized.